# Converting a sine or triangle wave into a sawtooth wave

Tags: c++, math, audio, waveform, wave

I'm trying to generate different wave forms in c++. So far I managed the sine, triangle and square wave, but I fail to get an idea how to generate a sawtooth wave.

This is how my sine wave looks like:

```
uint8_t sample = (amp * envelope * sin(2 * M_PI * phase)) + 128;
```

And this is the triangle wave:

```
double sinevalue = sin(2 * M_PI * phase);
uint8_t sample = (envelope * 2 * amp) / M_PI * asin(sinevalue) + 128;
```

How can I convert it into a sawtooth wave?

Comment: Why are you computing a sine value and then taking the arcsin of it? That seems computationally extravagant for no apparent reason.

Comment: I mean, you can compute a sawtooth wave like this (straight off wikipedia): y(x) = - (2 * amp)/pi * arctan(cot(x*pi/period))

Comment: @Logicrat `arcsin(sin(x))` gives `x` modulo `2Pi` to be in `[-Pi/2,Pi/2]`.  So there's a reason, but you're right that it's too much computation for what it's trying to do.

Comment: Do a search for Fourier Series and Transforms and mathematically speaking this should help http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SawtoothWave.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html

Comment: why not use something easy like `y=Amplitude*(t%Tperiod)` on integers or use `a=a/b; a=a-floor(a)`  instead of `a=a%b` on floats ??? or use precomputed table ... why to heck you want to transform sinwave? Or this should be filter that should process sinwave signal and transform it to saw tooth?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a sample-by-sample conversion of a sine wave to a sawtooth wave. That's because the sine wave is symmetric in time: if you reverse time, then except for some possible phase shift you get the same wave. For a swatooth wave a time reversal has to be combined with a sign reversal, the only time-reversed version will look qualitatively different.

You need some additional information, like e.g. the slope at the current position. Or you need access to the raw parameter value, in which case the formula would be *very* easy:

```
uint8_t sample = (amp * envelope * (phase - floor(phase));
```